# Scroll to next or previous DIV on click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a dynamic form/div which has a clone button on the right bottom corner. Once you click it, it should clone the `.item:first` and then auto scroll down so the last div will hide. and when you click on prev or next button, it should scroll to the exact div that i want.currently my approach by using `scrollTop` with fixed `px` but it is not effective. since we have a lot of screen size. How can I achieve this?  Thanks

```js
var template = $('#section .item:first').clone();

var sectionsCount = 1;

$('.new-div').click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: '+=700'
  }, 800);
});

$('body').on('click', '.new-div', function() {
  sectionsCount++;

  var section = template.clone().find('.item').each(function() {}).end()

    .appendTo('#section');
  return false;

});

$(".next").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: '+=700'
  }, 800);

});
$(".prev").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: '-=700'
  }, 800);

});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

#section {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 50px;
}

.item {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.new-div {
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: inherit;
  font-family: helvetica;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #eee;
}

.prev {
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 180px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: inherit;
  font-family: helvetica;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #eee;
}

.next {
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: inherit;
  font-family: helvetica;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section">
  <div class="item">
    <h1 class="head">Div</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="" class="new-div">New div</a>
<a href="" class="prev">prev</a>
<a href="" class="next">next</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the offset of the desired DIV using `topPos = element.offsetTop;` and then scroll to its position. More info can be accessed here about [offsetTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop) here.

```
 topPos = element.offsetTop;
 $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: topPos
 }, 800);
```

The code can be utilized like this.

Jquery :

```
 topPos = $($(".item")[0]).position().top;
 $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: topPos+"px"
 }, 800);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! i try  but it didn't work somehow. this is what i try : `$('.new-div').click(function(){
  topPos = $(".item").offsetTop;
 $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: topPos
 }, 800);
});`

Comment: because you are accessing through class. To achieve the result you should use $($(".item")[index] ) index is the number of the div. Another error as you are mixing vanilla code with jquery let me update the code with jquery too. In jquery, you should use position.

Comment: @Akbar change `$(".item").offsetTop` to `$(".item").offset().top`, and from `scrollTop: topPos` to `scrollTop: topPos + 'px'`

Comment: thanks @Jason gonna try it now . i will get back soon

Comment: @UllasHunka  when i clone new div it's auto scroll to the first div which i don't want . then i try to use `$($(".item")[2]).position().top;` and `$($(".item").next()[0]).position().top;` it works to 3rd div but it still not effective cuz i need to change the variable whenever i clone new div. 

the right way is : when i clone new div , all the previous div will auto scrolldown / hide.  sorry i'm kinda newbie hehe

Comment: @Akbar scroll to `section.offset().top`: 
    $('.new-div').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      sectionsCount++;

      var section = template.clone().find('.item').each(function() {}).end().appendTo('#section');

      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: section.offset().top + 'px'
      }, 800);
    });

Comment: it works perfectly what i want @Jason !!!! now i'm moving on to prev and next button!! thank you very much